# Using the same font as genlist uses

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

In Tizen, there is a genlist component, which uses `1text` as listitem class.

I want to use the *same* font style and size as this genlist uses in my label component.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried:

- `font=Tizen:style=Regular`
- `font=Tizen:style=Light`
- `font=TizenSans:style=Regular`
- `font=TizenSans:style=Light`

But none of them seems to match the one genlist uses by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you talking about SDK or real product cause there are little differences.

in Tizen SDK,
font=Tizen:weight=Regular font_size=38

in real product I guess,
font=Tizen:weight=Normal:width=Condensed font_size=38.

so the Condensed part is what you think it is different.
please have a try.

Comment: Almost perfect but not size is actually 36 and not 38. Thanks!

Comment: Do I have any chance to somehow use the system's default text styles in my EDC? So rather than defining my own style copying the system's ones just use something like `text_class: "system_default_list_title";`?